# how do upgrade to java 11? thinkorswim says I need it?

Tags: java

[image: Message requesting Java11]

THinkorswim has detected an old version of Java and asking me to change to Java 11. How do I do that?

Comment: keep simple please. I have very limited technical knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: What is thinkorswim? How it was installed?

Comment: java11 : `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`

Comment: @ Guiverc Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: @ N0rbert. Thinkorswim is TDameritrade stock and options trading platform

Comment: @KnudLarsen I got an error:   `Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Assume `thinkorswim_installer.sh` : Zulu openjdk 11 is required, not Oracle ! ..... Zulu https://docs.azul.com/core/zulu-openjdk/install/debian → `sudo apt install zulu11-jdk` .

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 : The default openjdk-11 is also perfect with Thinkorswim. See my first comment.